# symfony2 / doctrine2 - dql subselect

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

is it possible to get data with a subselect in dql and putting the result in a class attribute which is not a entity column?

**hasfreelist** is a class attribute but not a entity column in mysql.

This is my dql:

```
SELECT e, DATE(e.begin) dbegin, 
(SELECT COUNT(g) FROM AcmeDemoBundle:list  g WHERE e.id = g.fkevent) AS e.hasfreelists     
FROM AcmeDemoBundle:event e JOIN e.fklocation l 
WHERE e.enabled=1 e.begin>=:from 
ORDER BY dbegin, e.topevent DESC
```

I have the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("[Syntax Error] line 0, col 143: Error: 
Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'")
```

But it tells me nothing.
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you can define an association between `Event` and `List`, and use the [`SIZE` function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) to add your select. Much easier and logical that way:

```
SELECT e, DATE(e.begin) AS dbegin, SIZE(e.lists) AS number_of_lists
FROM [...]
```

You can still define a `hasFreeList` method on your entity class, which would return `sizeof($this->lists) > 0`.

But the reason you are getting this error, I think, is because you define your subselect as `e.hasfreelist`. While it is a property of your class, this is a DQL syntax error (should be `(SELECT x FROM y) AS z`). Also, your Date select lacks the `AS` operator.